# Is there a way to set English as a default language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I localized my app for 2 languages (EN, FR). When iPhone language set to English, app shows up in English. When iPhone language set to French, app shows up in French. But when iphone language set to another language lets say Spanish app shows up in French not in English.

I set "Localization native development region" to "en" or "United States" in my Info.plist file but didn't help.

Main.storyboard (Base) also in English.

Comment: Try setting the phone to another language that is less related to French, see if that changes things. The other thing to check is `Settings.app ➪ General ➪ Language & Region`'s Preferred Language Order, if French is above English it will be used ahead of English no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

One way to do it is to get the English string from `en.lproj` if the preferred language does not match `en` or `fr`.

This is how you get the preferred language:

```
let preferredLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```

This is how you get the English string using your localized key:

```
if let enPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj") {
            let enBundle = Bundle(path: enPath)
            enBundle?.localizedString(forKey: "your_key_here", value: nil, table: nil)
}
```

### Explanation of your problem:

In iOS native Settings App -> General -> Language & Region, there is a *Preferred Language Order* list.

> Apps and websites will use the first language in this list that they
>   support.

For example:

1. Set "French" as your iPhone Language.
2. Open the App and everything is localized in French because your app does support French.
3. Set "Spanish" as your iPhone Language.
4. Open the App and everything is localized in French because your app does **not** support Spanish and it'll fall through your next preferred language which is French in this case.

Answer (score 0):

***Just set developer language to English***

`YOURPROJECT.xcodeproj` -> `show package content` -> Editing the **.pbxproj** file directly using a text editor - look out for the **developmentRegion** property

[image]

And change the **Localizations native development region** property in the **Info.plist** accordingly `en` Or bellow image

[image]

once your result like this then you setup successfully  :
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtITv.png)

Comment: developmentRegion, Info.plist and project navigator settings already like this. But this doesn't force to "EN" if someone's language is like Japanese etc.

Comment: if you someone's language is like Japanese then what kind of output you looking for ?

Comment: then my solution should worked please try with my step from first